# Trying to scrape data from amazon

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to find the title of the results from a amazon search, but i can't find them.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=folie'
c = requests.get(url)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(c.content, 'lxml')

data_search = soup.find_all('ul', {'id': 's-results-list-atf'})

for link in data_search:
    print(link.contents[0].find_all('a',
                                    {
                                        'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal'}))
```

I don't get any result at the moment and i don't know why

[image]

Trying to get this header

EDIT:

Trying to get the brand:
[image]

Trying to get the brand of the product, but my console just getting spammed..

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
from lxml import etree

browser2 = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('https://login.live.com')
cookies = dict(res.cookies)

request2 = s.get(
    'https://www.amazon.de/BB-Verpackungen-Stretchfolie-transparent-Palettenfolie-Wickelfolie/dp/B004W3O4PS',
    headers=browser2)
soup2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(request2.content, 'lxml')


start = soup2.find_all('div', class_='centerColAlign')

for s in start:
    brand = s.find_all('div', class_='a-section a-spacing-none')
    for b in brand:
        s = b.find_all('a', {'id': 'bylineInfo'})
        for i in s:
            print(i.text)
```

[image]

Comment: I think amazon dont allow to access witout using API. Print soup before loop. U will see some checkpoint.

Comment: You can always scrap a website, you don't need access to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it and modifed two thing:

1. User agent
2. Removed double space between classes

There is the code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=folie'
c = requests.get(url, headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0'})
#print(c.content)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(c.content, 'html.parser')

data_search = soup.find_all('ul', {'id': 's-results-list-atf'})


for link in data_search:
    #print(link)
    #print(type(link))
    f = link.find_all('a', { 'class' : 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal' })
    #print(f)
    for a in f:
        print(a)
```

And there is the result of this code:

```
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A00173582V1J1Z4JYCC99&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2FAuto-Folie-selbstklebend-BLASENFREI-Klebefolie%2Fdp%2FB00TDS0PVE%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%2F259-1606642-0146458%3Fie%3DUTF8%26qid%3D1548365739%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26keywords%3Dfolie%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1548365739&amp;id=7589640135518839&amp;widgetName=sp_atf" title="4€/m² Auto Folie - schwarz matt - 3 x 1,5 meter selbstklebend BLASENFREI flexibel Car Wrapping Klebefolie"><h2 class="a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal" data-attribute="4€/m² Auto Folie - schwarz matt - 3 x 1,5 meter selbstklebend BLASENFREI flexibel Car Wrapping Klebefolie" data-max-rows="2"><span class="a-offscreen">[Gesponsert]</span>4€/m² Auto Folie - schwarz matt - 3 x 1,5 meter selbstklebend BLASENFREI flexibel Car Wrapping Klebefolie</h2></a>
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" href="/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_2?ie=UTF8&amp;adId=A03283802DFVL9Z711KMN&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2FFOSHIO-T%25C3%25B6nungsfolie-Installation-Cuttermesser-Werkzeugtasche%2Fdp%2FB06XNRKD2X%2Fref%3Dsr_1_2_sspa%2F259-1606642-0146458%3Fie%3DUTF8%26qid%3D1548365739%26sr%3D8-2-spons%26keywords%3Dfolie%26psc%3D1&amp;qualifier=1548365739&amp;id=7589640135518839&amp;widgetName=sp_atf" title="FOSHIO Autofolie Wrapping Werkzeug Kit für Auto Tönungsfolie Installation Mit Magnete Filz, Schaber Kuststoff,Rakel mit Filzkante, Cuttermesser,Folienrakel und Handschuhe, Werkzeugtasche"><h2 class="a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal" data-attribute="FOSHIO Autofolie Wrapping Werkzeug Kit für Auto Tönungsfolie Installation Mit Magnete Filz, Schaber Kuststoff,Rakel mit Filzkante, Cuttermesser,Folienrakel und Handschuhe, Werkzeugtasche" data-max-rows="2"><span class="a-offscreen">[Gesponsert]</span>FOSHIO Autofolie Wrapping Werkzeug Kit für Auto Tönungsfolie Installation Mit Magnete Filz, Schaber Kuststoff,Rakel mit Filzkante, Cuttermesser,Folienrakel und Handschuhe, Werkzeugtasche</h2></a>
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" href="https://www.amazon.de/BB-Verpackungen-Stretchfolie-transparent-Palettenfolie-Wickelfolie/dp/B004W3O4PS/ref=sr_1_3/259-1606642-0146458?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1548365739&amp;sr=8-3&amp;keywords=folie" title="BB-Verpackungen Hand Stretchfolie 23 my (transparent) 500 mm x 285 m, Palettenfolie Handfolie Wickelfolie"><h2 class="a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal" data-attribute="BB-Verpackungen Hand Stretchfolie 23 my (transparent) 500 mm x 285 m, Palettenfolie Handfolie Wickelfolie" data-max-rows="2">BB-Verpackungen Hand Stretchfolie 23 my (transparent) 500 mm x 285 m, Palettenfolie Handfolie Wickelfolie</h2></a>
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal" href="https://www.amazon.de/Neoxxim-22%E2%82%AC-Premium-blasenfrei-Luftkan%C3%A4len/dp/B01MYTRMXY/ref=sr_1_4/259-1606642-0146458?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1548365739&amp;sr=8-4&amp;keywords=folie" title="Neoxxim 24,22€/m2 Premium - Auto Folie - MATT - SCHWARZ - SCHWARZ MATT 30 x 150 cm - blasenfrei mit Luftkanälen ca 0,15mm dick für Auto Folierung folieren bekleben"><h2 class="a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal" data-attribute="Neoxxim 24,22€/m2 Premium - Auto Folie - MATT - SCHWARZ - SCHWARZ MATT 30 x 150 cm - blasenfrei mit Luftkanälen ca 0,15mm dick für Auto Folierung folieren bekleben" data-max-rows="2">Neoxxim 24,22€/m2 Premium - Auto Folie - MATT - SCHWARZ - SCHWARZ MATT 30 x 150 cm - blasenfrei mit Luftkanälen ca 0,15mm dick für Auto Folierung folieren bekleben</h2></a>
```

---

I hope it will work properly after that!

---

EDIT: 
It looks like javascript manipulate with html code so it's necessary to little bit modify first find_all(). After that I got 34 results instead of 4 with first code.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=folie'
c = requests.get(url, headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0'})
#print(c.content)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(c.content.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""), 'html.parser')   #remove comments tags

data_search = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 's-result-list'})

count = 0
for link in data_search:
    #print(link)
    #print(type(link))
    f = link.find_all('a', { 'class' : 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal' })
    #print(f)
    for a in f:
        print(a)
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Seriously the problem were the blank spaces?. Well, thank you. Do you know why are there just showing the first four results as output? There should be 30 outputs. Any idea?

Comment: No, problem was also in user agent. With default python requests user agent amazon knows that you are not human.
For second question, I edited code for removing comments tags from html and searching by class "s-result-list". Now it should work properly after that.

Comment: Now it's working! So i will remember for the next time, i am gonna try to use different tags. Thank you pretty much Matej!

Comment: Matej, please help me again... I am searching now for results which are a advertisment, but if i am searching for them i have again problems. You said the javascript manipulates the HTML code. Is there a way to request the page after the html code was manipulated? I think this would be easier for me to extract the data i need.

Comment: I think that without running javascript there is no way to get modifed html. The easiest way (in my opinion) is to temporarily disable javascript in your browser and inspect the html returned by server.

Comment: Worked great for the first page to get all i need, but now on the product page i have again a problem. I am trying to get the brand of the product (i just edited my question). I really don't know how to get it this time... Would be great, if you could help me again

Comment: I found the solution bymyself, i though searching with         s = b.find_all('div', {'class': 'bylineInfo'}) and s = b.find_all('div',class_= 'bylineInfo') is the same, but there are pretty much for loops, but i think faster it couldn't be right?

Comment: Honestly I don't know but class_ will be maybe faster than "class". So does it work now?

Comment: I don't know what the difference is, but {'class': 'bylineInfo'} hastn't worked at all. It just showed me like the whole page. Yes it's working now.